# Pass URL parameters through to next page with Javascript (or not)

Tags: javascript, url, parameters

I think this is simple but can't seem to find the answer.

In our autoresponder, when a contact clicks a link to visit a page, the contact id and email are passed through to the next page.

So by clicking an email, the contact lands on page.com/1/?id=123&email=name@gmail.com

On that page, and there is a button to click to go to the next page...

what do I need to do so the parameters pass to the next page and the contact lands on page.com/2/?id=123&email=name@gmail.com?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you written any code to try and resolve this?

Comment: There are a lot of solutions, but I cannot provide the solution. because you didn't give any code.

Comment: I'll be more descriptive to help... I am using LeadPages Drag and Drop page builder. The contact clicks a link inside an email and lands on baseurl.com/lesson-1 with ?id=[contactid]&email=[contactemail].

There is 1 button on the page that reads "View Next Lesson" and 1 line for me to paste the next URL (baseurl.com/lesson-2) into. I want those passed through to the next page, which I believe means I need to append a variable to the end of the url.

I am early into learning front-end dev, so I apologize if I haven't been perfectly descriptive so far.

Answer (score 0):

If the page number is all that changes:

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const currentPage = Number(window.location.href.match(/\d+/));
  window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/\d+/, currentPage + 1);
});
```

Comment: The question is pretty vague and there's no code provided. What if it was a submit button sending form data? Also, the URL may have other numbers

Comment: The question looked to be pretty clear to me - "from a page such as `page.com/1/?id=123`, how to get a button click to land on `page.com/2/?id=123`"? The parameters are already in the URL when on the first page, so it says.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. If the url has to change, which is not uncommon, this will break.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: here is a function to get the querystring parameters
from [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

```
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));

}
```

If you already know the base url, and have the parameters just combine the two and redirect.

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
     var url = "page.com/2"; //get your base url how ever you're doing it.
     var queryString = "?id=123&email=name@gmail.com";
     var fullUrl = url + queryString;
     window.location.href = fullUrl ;
};
```